# How can I know the number of subscribers of a channel with the youtube API using php?

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to make a YouTube Subscriber counter to put it on my website. But I don't know what the code in php is like to use the `YouTube v3` API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an API key(if you don't have):
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

You will need the channel id(You can obtain it from the URL):
https://www.youtube.com/channel/{channel_id}

Here is a simple PHP program using file_get_contents:

```php
<?php

$apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

//https://www.youtube.com/channel/{channel_id}
$channel_id = 'UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ';

$response = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id='. $channel_id .'&key='. $apiKey);

$data = json_decode($response);

$subscriber_count = $data->items[0]->statistics->subscriberCount;

echo $subscriber_count;
```

Note: You can improve it by adding error handling. You can also use curl or a library like Guzzle instead of file_get_contents if you can.

You can learn more about the channel resource here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels

Comment: I need one more if is not a problem: How can I know the number of views of a channel with the youtube API using php?

Comment: There is a viewCount property $view_count = $data->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;